# ¿Cómo limitar la cantidad de dígitos introducidos en java con joptionpane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

Tengo este código y lo que quiero hacer es hallar la manera de poder limitar la cantidad de dígitos que introduzca el usuario, específicamente no más de 6.

En otras palabras, quiero que cuando aparezca la caja de texto si fueras a insertar un numero tipo `1234567`, que arroje una pestaña de error.

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

```
public int getLeerE() throws IOException 
   {
      int ce = 0;
      boolean bandera = false;      
      do
      {
         try
         {         
       ce = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dame la edad: "));
       bandera = true;     
         }
         catch(NumberFormatException e)
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error ingresa un dato valido " ); 
         }
      } while (bandera != true);   
      return ce;
   }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no validar si la cantidad de dígitos introducidos es mayor a 6, en lugar de frenar al usuario a que introduzca más de 6 dígitos?

Comment: En lugar del **bandera = true** podrías poner un **if( ce.length < 7 ) { bandera  = true; }**.